# Previous / Next buttons in html?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, navigation

I want to create a navigation for the News section on my website, where when the buttons will be clicked it will navigate the user to the next or previous html.

The button must add or remove a number on the end of the html name so if first html is news.html and next button is clicked it should go to news1.html etc.

I suppose this can be achieved with javascript, how do I start?

Comment: Can we see your page as you have it now? We would need more to work off of to even give you a little bit of help.

Comment: Yes here it is: http://metallica-gr.net  The first page contains around 12 news articles right now, it's an external html called News.html that loads in the main body.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `window.location` to get the current page, match it with a regex to get the number at the end (if it exists) and then just increment it to get the next page and decrement it for the previous page. Of course, you'll have to work out how to handle the first and last pages.

For example, something like this might work:

```
var regex = /news(\d*)\.html/;
var index = +regex.exec(window.location.pathname)[1];
```

Now your index will either be blank (for `news.html`) or a number. You can then use that number to form the urls you need for you next and previous buttons.

```
var nextUrl = "news" + (index+1) + ".html";
var prevUrl = "news" + (index-1) + ".html";
```

Edit: This isn't the best way to do it, but here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr7tR/2/) to get you started.

Comment: Can you make a working example?(would be great) I am not sure how can I link the vars with the buttons. The link for the first news html page is http://metallica-gr.net/news/news.html

Comment: So, Matt I tried your code and checked out the fiddle, but it didn't work for me. The links don't get you to anywhere(I also tried putting void hrefs). Any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to get the url right, although I made the buttons to work, I do something wrong with the path to the next html.

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
```

then use regex to parse `path`, get the current number of page (if any) and turn it into a number, increase/decrease it and create your url from it.

However, I presume that you're not using ajax but some kind of server-side language and it would be better to do it server-side.

We can't do your homework for you. This is an example of testing for regex that accepts date string:

```
            // Date validation
        if (bdate != "")
        {
             if(!/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}(\.)?$/.test(bdate)||
             String(new Date(bdate.split(".")[1] + "/" + bdate.split(".")[0] + "/" + bdate.split(".")[2])) == "Invalid Date")        
            {return "Please enter a valid date in format dd.mm.yyyy"}
        }
```

In there, regex test is this expression: `/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}(\.)?$/.test(bdate)` and it tests if string `bdate` fits the regular expression.
regular expressions are objects that you can construct by putting operators between two forward slashes like above (`/operators/`).

[this is a reference for javascript regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) ant this is a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp).
I wish you luck :)

Btw, if you don't want to learn anything, you should probably consider using something like wordpress or maybe even tumblr.

Comment: Can you guys give me an example? I have no idea about regex. I only use html for my website.

Comment: It's not that I want you to do my homework, I thought it would be easier than the examples you guys gave me. For example in ActionScript that I am more familiar with, you would probably create a for loop and just add +1 to the href of the news.html. Can't we use a similar method in javascript?

Comment: @zefs: what are you going to loop through? Javascript will run client side *in* each individual page, so you have to work from the context of the current page and then figure out what would be the next page and what would be the previous page. Of course, if you can work on the server side instead, then this becomes an easier problem to deal with.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about that. The loop would probably work for something like an iframe only I suppose.

Comment: Exactly. Loop thru what? There will be only one "next" and one "previous".
Iframes really have no touching point with this question.

Comment: So if we had an iframe instead and added +1 on it's source html it wouldn't work? But we can't do this here since each news page is separate and must include the javascript code. That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: Yes, each page is separate. Doing this with iframes makes no sense.
What you should, definitely, do, is simply install wordpress with some pagination plugin or go with tumblr, as I suggested you.
Or learn real coding.
Cause doing this with static html & javascript makes no sense.

Comment: I made this question to ask specific how to create this for my website, not which CMS system to use. And what answer is this? "Learn real coding"? If I had the time to do that I wouldn't come here to ask for help. Instead of arguing about these things you could actually try to help me understand how to make the code work for my page.

Comment: I am not mocking you. I'm just telling you that what you're trying to do is very impractical.

You will lose a lot of time, you won't learn much and when you do it, your result won't be very great.

Using static html pages is just not how things are done.

Comment: That's how I wanted to build this website, using static html pages. Is it so hard to create a navigation like that? I am sure I could make it in Flash but I don't want to use that platform for something as important as a navigation. I always accept the answers that solve my question/issue.